# Tinymce editor making textarea outside the iframe

Tags: angularjs, popup, tinymce-4

I am using tinymce 4.x editor in a popup in angularjs. It is creating editor but editor's iframe body don't have textarea. It is outside the iframe.

Comment: You are just making a statement of fact - that TinyMCE creates an iFrame and adds that to the DOM.  What question do you have?  What do you want help with?

Comment: my problem is that TinyMCE is creating Iframe but it adds DOM element outside the iFrame. It is working properly in a screen but when I am using popup then this problem occurs..

Comment: You still have not stated what "this problem" is that you are having.  If you want people to help you need to define the problem you are having.  I would recommend creating a JS Fiddle or CodePen that shows the issue you are having - this will allow people to see the issue and potentially provide suggestions.  Please see this note on creating a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve